# Linux Ubuntu, How to clean cookies from web browsers

Tags: linux, cookies, trash

How do I empty the trash though the terminal, and how do I get rid of cookies that have accumulated in the web browsers under linux?

Comment: Is there any special browser or do you really mean every browser so this could be very hard to accomplish as there are a lot of different browsers out there.

Comment: For most browsers the answer will be "In the same way as you clear cookies on OS X, windows or any other OS", since it would be browser specific and not OS specific.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm for Mozilla Firefox Browser:

1. `cd ~/.mozilla/firefox/asdfas.default/` the name of folder will another and must ends with .default/
2. `sqlite3 cookies.sqlite`
3. `DELETE FROM moz_cookies;`

Answer (score 0):

**[bleachbit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/)** - http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/ - it's like a CCleaner. Is a good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and Firefox-esr cookies can be deleted by follow:

```
rm /home/*/.mozilla/firefox/*.default*/cookies.sqlite
```

Be carfull. Dont delete wrong files.